# Is it possible to show gridlines in the background in vim?

Tags: vim, gvim, macvim

Is it possible to show gridlines in the background in vim (ideally each four characters)?  Or, if not possible in vim, is it possible in MacVim?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not really a grid but vertical lines, but i don't think you need a full grid, here is a plugin providing - almost a grid:

https://github.com/nathanaelkane/vim-indent-guides

Comment: Works well enough for now.  True grid system would be nice, though.